How to use paragraph shading with custom image?
I am working on a design for scientific posters for our research group and would like to apply a special paragraph shading to the headline of each box. I don't want a static color or a gradient, but rather a picture repeated as a pattern. Here is what the box looks like without:

The headline is shaded blue, I want this shading rather to be a picture, kinda like here:

Here, I just inserted a box as background and added some outer glow to the text, but this should work smootly if I resize the box to whatever width I need, like the normal shading functionality. This poster template will also be used by other people so it really should be easy to use.
Apparently, Indesign cannot work with patterns, as this post outlines:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-create-a-pattern-and-apply-it-in-indesign/td-p/8281180
I found this tutorial to create a pattern swatch, but this is not exactly what I need: https://creativepro.com/indesign-eye-candy-part-4-pattern-swatches/
So now I am asking, is there a way to link this image as text background to the text box while automatically adjusting to the box width, just like the paragraph shading does?
